# Crystal reports group properties

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

Ok this is a really specific question, but I can't seem to find the setting i need.

I'm doing crystal reports inside of vs.net 2005, and i need a page header, and report header, but i need the page header to come BEFORE the report header. Is this possible?

Basically i have two areas that I want at the top of the first page, A, followed by B.
Then I want A on the top of every subsequent page, but no more B.

Its like I want the Page Header to just appear ABOVE the Report Header.

I was hoping for some option per-group as to whether to repeat on page breaks, but I can't find any.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the way you describe it, Crystal can't do it. But you can achieve the same effect by doing the following :

1) Suppress the Report Header

2) Split the Page Header into 2 sections.

3) Place what you were going to place in the Report Header into the second of the Page Header sections.

4) Use a Conditional Suppression Formula on the second section to say "PageNumber > 1"